# java.lang.ClassFormatError JVMCFRE076 bad magic number

Tags: java

This question is partly solved. I will write about it since today google doesn’t provide that much help.

I have a webapp which is running fine on my local Ubuntu Linux Java environment. When I deploy it on a suse linux environment I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE076 bad magic number;
class=com/package/util/MongodbUtil, offset=0 Error: java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE076 bad magic number;
class=com/package/util/MongodbUtil, offset=0 /items added=0 /items deleted=0 /items unchanged=0
```

The problem derives from the Class name. The exception will only be thrown when it includes "Util" in the name. I renamed the Class to DbTool and it all worked fine. Digging a bit deeper it turned out that I can't include parts of the package name in the Class name.

I have a workaround which works, but I'm still interested to know why the exception was thrown and why it works on my local environment but not on the remote environment.

My local tomcat runs on open JDK 1.6.0_27 and the remote tomcat runs on IBM JRE 1_6_0. Both environments uses tomcat 6.36

Comment: I very much doubt it that if you have a package containing `util` in the name your class name cannot also contain `util` (upper or lowercase) -- the problem is definitely somewhere else. To counter what you said, look at `StringUtils` in the Spring framework -- it's under package 'org.springframework.util` and it works perfectly fine!

Comment: It's been a while since you posted this answer, but I'll put a comment anyway. Just stumbled upon this bizarre error first time after almost 10 years of hanging out with Java. In my case it was caused by corrupted class file - if you want more details, I can post as a separate answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The problem for me was solved when I change from IBM JRE to Oracle JRE. I still don't know the reason for this. You could always post your answerer, it may help some one in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason caused this problem is that you have used different java virtual machine(`Sun HotSpot VM and IBM J9 VM`) while compling and running, in other words, this issue won't appear by unitizing the compling and runtime environment.

Comment: I would like to test this, but it's a bit complicated to install the IBM JDK.